# How do I make the AltGr+Shift switch languages in Manjaro Linux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, manjaro

For 16 years I've been using the <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch between languages in Windows. But in Linux it uses the left one.
Is there a way to make language switching by the right one?

I'm using Manjaro Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Many keyboard layouts use <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> (aka <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) by default for accessing 3rd and 4th level symbols. Hence, in order to make the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut work for switching input languages, you need to explicitly select some other 3rd level key.

You may want to edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and consider this line to achieve what you want:

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_alt,lv3:lalt_switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

That combo turns <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> into the 3rd level key while <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> works for switching languages.

Comment: i did that but it's not working

Comment: @AhmadKhalafalla: It probably requires a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which OS you are using but for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I am using this command to switch between languages:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle us
```

If you want to change between languages, replace `us` by your desired language. For example, if you want to use German keyboard change it to `de`:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle de
```

Comment: it's work, but how to make a shortcut to do this command?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by shortcut. But you can just create a bash script put this command into the script, make the script executable and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type:

```
cd
vi lang-switch.sh
```

Press ins button on your keyboard and paste:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle de
```

Then press Esc button on your keyboard. Then type :x to save and close. Then type:

```
sudo chmod +x lang-switch.sh
```

Eventually see the solution here: [click](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-add-a-switch-keyboard-language-shortcut-flushed/9666/5)